# Change range value based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need to show a range if cell.value (`D2`) is less than today and another of cell.value (`D2`) is greather than today.

The copying and pasting may consume too much from excel, and it is not working anyway, is there another way to do this?

The cell value is always `J3:AB3` , don´t matter what date is in `D2`

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim C As Range
Set C = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SIN").Range("D2")

If CDate(C.Value) <= Date Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PARA").Range("J2:AB2").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SIN").Range("D5:V5")
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PARA").Range("J3:AB3").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SIN").Range("D5:V5")     
End If
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Looks ok to me.

Comment: I have decided to go with the simple substitute formula on the cell instead of VBA. However, what I meant was: The range is always ("j3:ab3"), it never feches ("j2:ab2"), but it´s ok.

Comment: Maybe because this condition is not met `CDate(C.Value) <= Date`, so the action of the `Else` is done, you should post some data. And instead of copy/paste, write the cell directly, like: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SIN").Range("D5:V5") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PARA").Range("J2:AB2")`

Comment: danieltakeshi guessed correctly. that did it!